# Socket connection between two emulators

Tags: android, sockets, android-emulator, adb

I want to connect two Android emulators (both running on the same host) with sockets.

I have a server running on one of them and listening to the 7000 port on the external IP address:

```
        InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName("10.0.2.15");
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(7000, 50, addr);
        try {
            sock = serverSocket.accept();
        } finally {
            serverSocket.close();
        }
```

and a client on a different emulator on the same host connecting to that port:

```
         socket = new Socket();
         socket.bind(new InetSocketAddress("10.0.2.15", 6666));
         socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("10.0.2.2", 7000));
```

I have bound the client to the 6666 port so I can do the adb port forwarding necessary:

```
         (host) .\adb.exe forward --list
         emulator-5554 tcp:7000 tcp:7000
         emulator-5556 tcp:6666 tcp:6666
```

I can see with the debugger that the client socket is in "connected" state, but calling:

```
        dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
        dataInputStream.available(); // this throws IOException Broken Pipe
```

throws an IOException of Broken Pipe.

Any ideas where the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Using **redir** instead of **adb forward** seems to solve the problem.

On the server emulator

```
telnet locahost 5554
redir add tcp:7000:7000
```

On the client emulator

```
telnet localhost 5556
redir add tcp:6666:6666
```

I don't really understand why there is a difference, as [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking#redirection) states:

"*The Android Debug Bridge (adb) tool provides port forwarding, an alternate way for you to set up network redirection.*"